# Calendar - Only display available resources

Tags: jquery, calendar, newform

I have a resource calendar. Is there a way to limit the resources based on the date user picks when they want to reserve a resource. For example, user clicks on 1-26-2015 date and conf room 3, 4, and 7 already booked. Is there a way to remove these since they are not available for that date from the resource drop down? We have over 100 conference rooms and users are getting annoyed when they go through bunch of conference rooms that are already booked.

Comment: There is no straight forward way to achieve this. You should either use client side to get this data using `jQuery` `ajax` `caml` and update the resources list OR use server side object model to create a custom New/Edit form.